# Edittext Exception in SubscribeActivity: Null Pointer Exception error

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, fatal-error

i have code for subscribing the activity but when i enter the send button to insert it i am getting fatal exception i check it in google but i didnt find the solution to my problem . i am getting error after the connection success message. I have added internet permission as well then what might be issue can any one help

```
public class SubscribeActivity extends Activity {

    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    private EditText edittext_first;
    private EditText edittext_last;
    private EditText edittext_age;
    private EditText edittext_email;
    private EditText edittext_confirm;
    private Button send;
    String v5,v1,v2,v3,v4,v6;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.subscribe);

        edittext_first = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstname);
        edittext_last = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastname);
        edittext_age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age1);
        edittext_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        edittext_confirm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confirm);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                boolean isValid = true;
                if (edittext_first.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                    edittext_first.setError("VALUE REQUIRED");
                    isValid = false;
                } else if (!edittext_first.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) {
                    edittext_first.setError("ENTER ONLY ALPHABETS");
                    isValid = false;
                }

                if (edittext_last.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                    edittext_last.setError("VALUE REQUIRED");
                    isValid = false;
                } else if (!edittext_last.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) {
                    edittext_last.setError("ENTER ONLY ALPHABETS");
                    isValid = false;
                }

                if (edittext_age.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                    edittext_age.setError("VALUE REQUIRED");
                    isValid = false;
                } else if (!edittext_age.getText().toString().matches("[0-9 ]+")) {
                    edittext_age.setError("ACCEPT NUMBERS");
                    isValid = false;
                }

                if (edittext_email.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                    edittext_email.setError("VALUE REQUIRED");
                    isValid = false;
                } else if (!isEmailValid(edittext_email.getText().toString())) {
                    edittext_email.setError("INVALID EMAIL");
                    isValid = false;
                }


                if (edittext_confirm.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                    edittext_confirm.setError("VALUE REQUIRED");
                    isValid = false;
                } else if (!isEmailValid(edittext_confirm.getText().toString())) {
                    edittext_email.setError("INVALID EMAIL");
                    isValid = false;
                } else if (!edittext_confirm.getText().toString().equals(edittext_email.getText().toString())) {
                    edittext_confirm.setError("PASSWORD MISMATCH");
                    isValid = false;
                }

                v1 = edittext_first.getText().toString();
                v2 = edittext_last.getText().toString();
                v3 = edittext_age.getText().toString();
                v4 = edittext_email.getText().toString();
                v5 = edittext_confirm.getText().toString();

                if (isValid) {
                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname", v1));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname", v2));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", v3));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email_address", v4));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("confirm_email_address", v5));

                    submitDataOnServer(nameValuePairs);
                }
            }

        });

    }

    public void submitDataOnServer(final ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs){
        new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>(){
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.137/Android/App/getInsert.php");
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();

                    Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
                    System.out.println("Zero");
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Subscription Successfull.Thank You for Subscribing you have now been added to our Mailing Lists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                try {
                    System.out.println("First");
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    System.out.println("Second");
                    System.out.println("After Second:"+reader.readLine());
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");

                    }
                    is.close();
                    System.out.println("Third");
                    result=sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Fourth");
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                try {
                    System.out.println("Fifth");
                    JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                    CharSequence w = (CharSequence) json_data.get("result");

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), w, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                    System.out.println("sixth");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }


    public boolean isEmailValid(final String mailAddress) {
        Pattern pattern;
        Matcher matcher;
        final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@" + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
        pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(mailAddress);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
}
```

And the logcat is showing Component info error

```
Logcat:

    08-01 06:37:56.230: E/log_tag(3328): connection success 
08-01 06:37:56.330: D/AndroidRuntime(3328): Shutting down VM
08-01 06:37:56.330: W/dalvikvm(3328): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a1bba8)
08-01 06:37:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3328): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 06:37:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3328): Process: com.example.audioplay, PID: 3328
08-01 06:37:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3328): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 06:37:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
08-01 06:37:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
08-01 06:37:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:155)
08-01 06:37:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
08-01 06:37:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at com.example.audioplay.SubscribeActivity$2.onPostExecute(SubscribeActivity.java:174)
08-01 06:37:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at com.example.audioplay.SubscribeActivity$2.onPostExecute(SubscribeActivity.java:1)
08-01 06:37:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
08-01 06:37:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-01 06:37:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
08-01 06:37:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-01 06:37:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-01 06:37:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-01 06:37:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 06:37:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-01 06:37:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-01 06:37:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-01 06:37:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Edittext xml file for subscribe
  subscribe.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:src="@drawable/deadoralive" />

        <requestFocus
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/record_sofya"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Join Our Mailing List - Join Today to Receive your Free Download"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/firstname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Enter First Name"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/lastname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Enter Last Name"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/age1"
                android:numeric="integer"
                android:maxLength="2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Enter Age"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Enter Email Address"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/confirm"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Confirm Email Address"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/send"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:text="Send"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is line 31 of Another.java?

Comment: @MysticMagic nothing after passing it has to go to another java which is dummy file

Comment: That line is getting Null pointer exception. Can you show that line?

Comment: @MysticMagic friend give me two minutes i will take that out and send you the logcat

Comment: What is code inside Another.onCreate()

Comment: @ANNNCHOOOR That line is the problem. We won't be able to help you without knowing the code.

Comment: @MysticMagic if i delete that line also i will get an error

Comment: Solve the errors step by step. Firstly, solve this NPE. Then solve another error.

Comment: @MysticMagic i took the intent out and check it and i am getting this kind of error

Comment: @MysticMagic wait i will edit it 2 minutes

Comment: @MysticMagic just check the edited code sister and please help me now here what is the trouble

Comment: There is NPE at line JSONTokener.java:116. So Please don't go removing lines which causes issue. Instead, solve them. Check what's causing NullPointer and prevent it! Happy coding.

Comment: @MysticMagic no actually i have added to check up whether it will get corrected but it lead me somewhere. so i edited . Can u please help me in doing and handling exception pls

Comment: @ANNNCHOOOR I Can not help without seeing the line which is causing the NPE. Can you please show the line JSONTokener.java:116?

Comment: @MysticMagic yes nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname", v1)); this line in above code

Comment: Ok. Have you initialized nameValuePairs as `new ArrayList` or whatever it is? Please debug what is null in that line.

Comment: No i am printing all and checked everything is fine but NPE is showing in this line now ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

Comment: Ya i have inilialized in above code @MysticMagic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58485/discussion-between-annn-chooor-and-mysticmagic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **doInBackground** you are return `null` please 
`return result` or any other string (you want to use in `JSON`) from `doInBackground`

```
public void submitDataOnServer(final ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs){
        new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>(){
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.137/Android/App/getInsert.php");
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();

                    Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
                    System.out.println("Zero");
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Subscription Successfull.Thank You for Subscribing you have now been added to our Mailing Lists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                try {
                    System.out.println("First");
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    System.out.println("Second");
                    System.out.println("After Second:"+reader.readLine());
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");

                    }
                    is.close();
                    System.out.println("Third");
                    result=sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Fourth");
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                try {
                    System.out.println("Fifth");
                    JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                    CharSequence w = (CharSequence) json_data.get("result");

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), w, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                    System.out.println("sixth");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```